# Clear script error on next day form entries

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am using the following script to clear Google form entries at midnight each day.

```
function clearRange() {
    var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1DNeHRC41ryRY9s8wZmlqmoIEhm8MqD601BvqoV26V3o").getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
    sheetActive.getRange('A2:E').clearContent();
}
```

**Problem:**

- The following day, the form entries are added to the sheet starting at the row below the previous day's entries, not row 2.

**Example:**

- Yesterday, 10 form entries were entered on the sheet (rows 2 to 11). The script runs at midnight and clears the entries.
- Today, five entries were entered on the form but were entered from row 12 onwards.

I need the sheet to clear and reset, to start entering form entries in row 2 every day.

Is this possible? If so, what changes are needed to the formula?  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution:

Try to **delete** the rows instead:

```
function clearRange() {
  const sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1DNeHRC41ryRY9s8wZmlqmoIEhm8MqD601BvqoV26V3o").getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  const form_size = sheetActive.getLastRow()-1;
  sheetActive.deleteRows(2, form_size);
}
```

Before you start using this solution, only for the first time, delete manually all the rows; starting from the second row until the row before the new entry will be added. So the new entry will be at the second row.

### Recommendation:

However, it is not recommended to touch the **Form responses** sheet. I would advice you to create a separate sheet to query only the records of today and let the raw data be in the **Form responses** sheet. In this way, you don't need to clear or delete the old form entries, but you also don't touch the raw data which might be used as a reference in the future.

### References:

- [deleteRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition,-howmany)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)