# Make Google Form to keep updating the first row of Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using a Google Spreadsheet with Google Forms. When a new response from Google Forms comes in, I don't want it to increase the total rows in the Google Spreadsheet. I want to create a feature where a new response renews only the first row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear script error on next day form entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579726/clear-script-error-on-next-day-form-entries)

Comment: Can you provide more information about *what* exactly are you trying to achieve? @김민재

Answer (score 1):

You can't control where the **Form Responses** are going.

A solution is to create **a new tab** and leave the **Form Responses Tab** as it is. Then for the first row of that **new tab**, insert a formula to cite the last row of **Form Responses Tab**.

### Steps

1. Rename the **Form Responses Tab** to `abc`
2. Create a new tab, insert the following formula to the first cell. `=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("abc!A",ArrayFormula(max(if(len(abc!A:A),row(abc!A:A),))),":Z",ArrayFormula(max(if(len(abc!A:A),row(abc!A:A),)))))`